# Homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I am trying to find all homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_8$. I understand how to do it - one completely determines any homomorphism, say $\phi$, by computing multiples of $\phi(1)$ or more generally $\phi(g)$ where $g$ generates $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$. Call $\phi_i$ the mapping taking $1$ to $i$ in $\mathbb{Z}_8$. I don’t know how else to determine whether each $\phi_i$ is a homomorphism besides going through the painstaking process of calculating each $\phi_i(x+y)$ and comparing it to $\phi_i(x)+\phi_i(y)$.

Is there a way to easily rule out certain $\phi_i$s?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: I have heard of it but do not know it.

Comment: Well, first, you shouldn't be multiplying $x$ and $y$, you should be **adding** them. Second: if $g$ is a generator, then you need $\phi(20g) = 20\phi(g)$ to be $0$. So...

Comment: @Mirko: The CRT is irrelevant here. Look at the tags: these are additive groups and group homomorphisms, not rings.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin I’ll fix that now, wrote that in a rush. What do you mean by your second part?

Comment: I meant exactly what @Dave wrote in his answer. That whatever $\phi(g)\in\mathbb{Z}_8$ is, you need it to have order dividing $20$, and not every element of $\mathbb{Z}_8$ has order dividing $20$. That will let you "easily rule out certain $\phi_i$s".

Comment: That helps. Thank you.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Thank you for reply. The CRT does not answer the question, but reduces it to a simpler one. It is not irrelevant.

Comment: @Mirko: The CRT is about rings and ring homomorphisms. This is about groups.  It *is* irrelevant. What's more, if you "apply" it, you end up trying to figure out group homomorphisms from a direct product to a group, which means solving *two* problems instead of one. You didn't reduce it to a simpler problem, you applied a result that is not about groups to turn this problem into **two** problems of equal complexity.

Comment: The question does not specify if $\mathbb{Z}_n$ are groups or rings. I did not even read the tags.

Comment: @Mirko: Well, that's on you, then. Still makes your comment misleading at best, and irrelevant.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin There is no need to attack me.

Comment: @Mirko: I am not attacking you. I am pointing out that your first comment was misleading, and that if your justification is "I didn't read the tags", then  you should not blame the OP for omitting the information that was contained there.,

Comment: @ArturoMagidin All information that is relevant to the question belongs into the question text.

Comment: @Mirko I am correcting you lest your comments mislead future readers; if you were unsure whether they were groups or rings you should ask for clarification. Instead, you jumped to an unwarranted conclusion and posted information that was not helpful. When this was pointed out, you became defensive. Again, that's on you, not me and not the OP.

Comment: I wonder if you are really the famous mathematician in Lafayette, Louisiana sharing your name. If you are, then this discussion is below your level and not worth your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct about looking at $\phi(1)$: since $1$ generates the domain (i.e. $\mathbb Z_{20}$), you can just look at where $1$ gets sent under the homomorphism. The only other thing you need to check is that the homomorphism preserves the relations. There is one relation in $\mathbb Z_{20}$, namely $20=0$. So $\phi$ better send $20$ to $0$ in $\mathbb Z_8$ (i.e. a multiple of $8$). For example, if you have a map which sends $1$ to $3$, then this would send $20$ to $60$, which would mean it's not a homomorphism (since $60$ is not $0$ in $\mathbb Z_8$).

The real reason behind this is the universal property of quotients. Basically you're looking at group homomorphisms $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z_8$ (which are completely determined by where $1$ is sent, and you can send $1$ anywhere) and then asking that the kernel contains the ideal $20\mathbb Z\subseteq\mathbb Z$ so that it factors as a map $\mathbb Z_{20}\to\mathbb Z_8$.

Answer (score 1):

We need to find how many $i \in \mathbb{Z}_{8}$ satisfy the relation $20i=0$. There are only $8$ cases to consider:

1. $i=0$ works ($0$ is divisible by $8$)
2. $i=1$ doesn't work ($20$ is not divisible by $8$)
3. $i=2$ works ($40$ is divisible by $8$)
4. $i=3$ doesn't work ($60$ is not divisible by $8$)
5. $i=4$ works ($80$ is divisible by $8$)
6. $i=5$ doesn't work ($100$ is not divisible by $8$)
7. $i=6$ works ($120$ is divisible by $8$)
8. $i=7$ doesn't work ($140$ is not divisible by $8$)

So, there are exactly $4$ group homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{8}$. Only even values of $i$ work, and the odd values can be ruled out.

Comment: Why is it the case that they work just because $8$ divides $20i$? I understand the result on homomorphisms that if $g\in G$ then $|\phi(g)|$ divides $|g|$. But why in this case does this imply $\phi_i(x+y)=\phi_i(x)+\phi_i(y)$?

Comment: @MichaelCatliMath Because it's a **cyclic** group. Every element is of the form $kg$, so all you need is for $\phi(kg)$ to equal $k\phi(g)$. And this happens if and only if whenever $r\equiv s\pmod{20}$ (so that $rg=sg$) you have $r\phi(g)=s\phi(s)$, which happens if and only if $r\equiv s\pmod{|\phi(s)|}$. \

Answer (score 0):

By the First Homomorphism Theorem, the quotient $\Bbb Z_{20}/\operatorname{ker}\phi$ is isomorphic to the image of $\phi$. Since $|\operatorname{im}\phi|$ must be a common divisor of $20$ and $8$, the only possible options for the image of $\phi$ are:

1. $\operatorname{im}\phi=\{0\}$;
2. $\operatorname{im}\phi\cong \Bbb Z_2$;
3. $\operatorname{im}\phi\cong \Bbb Z_4$.

Option 1 corresponds to the trivial homomorphism: all the elements of $\Bbb Z_{20}$ are sent to $0$.

Option 2 would correspond to $\operatorname{ker}\phi\cong \Bbb Z_{10}$: $\operatorname{ker}\phi$ is sent to $0$, and $1+\operatorname{ker}\phi$ (which has order $2$ in the quotient) is sent to $4$. You can check that this is indeed a homomorphism.

Option 3 would correspond to $\operatorname{ker}\phi\cong \Bbb Z_{5}$:

- $\operatorname{ker}\phi$ is sent to $0$;
- $1+\operatorname{ker}\phi$ (which has order $4$ in the quotient) is sent to either $2$ or $6$;
- $2+\operatorname{ker}\phi$ (which has order $2$ in the quotient) is sent to $4$;
- $3+\operatorname{ker}\phi$ (which has order $4$ in the quotient) is sent to either $6$ or $2$, according to where $1+\operatorname{ker}\phi$ was sent to before.

You can check that both these are indeed homomorphisms.